# Applying changes from your project config files ... No site settings exist for section 20

Tags: deployment, project.yaml

Deploying on production is giving me this error.

Applying changes from your project config files ... No site settings exist for section 20

Deploying to stage is working no problem. Production isn't live yet. It uses the same database copied from stage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a new environment with your staging database, then run this on your new production environment:

`./craft project-config/rebuild`

This will force-dump the config into the project-config YAML files from scratch, and include any small changes that might have happened to make way for the new environment, including pesky caches.

Comment: Thanks very much. I ended up creating a new folder on the server and deploying to that instead. Just out of curiosity would doing that on production cause the yaml to be different to whats in git?

Comment: It all depends on how out of sync they ended up getting, but yes, it's possible. Any edits where a yaml file is removed, if your git re-adds the file and you `apply` them, the deleted content reappears. I've learned to use the database as the source of truth, not the yaml files.